# Invalid filter add_class using django-widget-tweaks

Tags: django, django-widget-tweaks

I am creating form view using django-widget-tweaks following this [tutorial.](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/2015/12/04/package-of-the-week-django-widget-tweaks.html)
When I tried to implement add_class filter, I got following error.

> Invalid filter: 'add_class'

Does anyone know how to solve this error?

**html page**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
(% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h4 style="margin-top: 0">Project Upload</h4>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
            {{hidden}}
        {% endfor %}

        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="{{field.id_for_label}}">{{field.label}}</label>
                {{field|add_class:"form-control"}}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**form.py**

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=html
        fields=['project','version','diff','program','location']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this-out [here](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/)

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

<!-- add 2 extra css classes to field element -->
{{ form.title|add_class:"css_class_1 css_class_2" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
{% render_field field|add_class:"form-group"%}
```